# How to add text to System.Windows.Controls.ListviewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

I can't find any way to add text to it.  I want to use it like a TreeViewItem's header but I can't find anything that allows me to change the text

with Treeview I can just do this

`TreeViewItem tvi = new TreeViewItem{Tag = obj, header = obj.name};`

but I can't find a way to do this with the listviewitem

`ListviewItem lvi = new ListviewItem{Tag = obj};`

Is there no way for me to change its text?

Answer (score 0):

Does this code help you?

```
ListView1.View = View.List;

Cursor[] favoriteCursors = new Cursor[]{Cursors.Help, 
    Cursors.Hand, Cursors.No, Cursors.Cross};

// Populate the ListView control with the array of Cursors.
foreach ( Cursor aCursor in favoriteCursors )
{

    // Construct the ListViewItem object
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();

    // Set the Text property to the cursor name.
    item.Text = aCursor.ToString();

    // Set the Tag property to the cursor.
    item.Tag = aCursor;

    // Add the ListViewItem to the ListView.
    ListView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has a `Content` property that you can set to a `string`:

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem { Content = "text..." } ;
```